# Only load audio file when link is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, audio

I made a custom audio/video manager that works fine. The problem is I didn't anticipate the person to add as many entries as they did and now it's pretty slow. Audio won't play right after the page loads for about 15-20 seconds, after that everything plays fine.

I query the database via php, followed by this jQuery:

```
<?php
  foreach($results as $row) {
?>
    var audioElement<?=$row[0]?> = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement<?=$row[0]?>.setAttribute('class', 'div-<?=$row[0]?>');
    audioElement<?=$row[0]?>.setAttribute('src', '<?=$row[4]?>');
    $.get();
    audioElement<?=$row[0]?>.addEventListener('load', function() {
        pause(playing);
        play(<?=$row[0]?>);
    }, true);
    $('.play<?=$row[0]?>').click(function() {
        if (playing==<?=$row[0]?>) {
            pause(<?=$row[0]?>);
        } else {
            pause(playing);
            play(<?=$row[0]?>);
        }
    });
<?php
```

}

`$row[0]` being the ID in the database and `$row[4]` the path to the audio file. I tried modifying it like so:

```
    <?php
      foreach($results as $row) {
    ?>
        var audioElement<?=$row[0]?> = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement<?=$row[0]?>.setAttribute('class', 'div-<?=$row[0]?>');

    // added the line below
    $('.play<?=$row[0]?>').click(function(){

        audioElement<?=$row[0]?>.setAttribute('src', '<?=$row[4]?>');

    // also added
    });
        $.get();
        audioElement<?=$row[0]?>.addEventListener('load', function() {
            pause(playing);
            play(<?=$row[0]?>);
        }, true);
        $('.play<?=$row[0]?>').click(function() {
            if (playing==<?=$row[0]?>) {
                pause(<?=$row[0]?>);
            } else {
                pause(playing);
                play(<?=$row[0]?>);
            }
        });
    <?php
  }
```

I was hoping to only load the audio file once the corresponding link is clicked, however, it still has the lag time on the first click. I ran tests at [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/) and the page speed was vastly improved after my edit and it showed that it wasn't loading the audio. So I'm not sure why it takes so long for it to play on the initial click.

Page with the issue: [Video/Music Gallery](http://smp-productions.com/videomusicgallery/)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing a 301 on the tracks that will slow things down a little, but it's still starting to play in half a second or so here...

Comment: @rjdown Yeah, my co worker moved the site for some reason and added the 301. It's playing that fast? You must be next door to the server lol  The owner of the site brought it to my attention, so he's having the same issue as well. The only time it plays that fast for me is after the initial play, then all play fine, or I load the page and let it sit for the same 15-20 seconds. Does it play that fast if you click right when the browser stops loading?

Comment: Yep, first track less than a second. ip2location says your server is in Arizona, US. I'm in the UK so far from being close!

Comment: Same on latest chrome and firefox by the way...

Comment: This weird because I'm in California. Thank you @rjdown for taking the time to do that.

Comment: I did find out one weird thing a bit. It's built on wordpress and when I'm NOT logged in, they play right away. I tried it in incognito mode too and works fine. It's only when I'm logged in that I have the issue.